# How to remove only lines that do not have text in TextField?

Tags: text, flutter, dart, textfield

I have some input text that contains multiple empty lines, and I want to remove only the lines that have no text before I put it into my TextField.

Example:

```
Hello, how are you?
// empty line
// empty line
With you?
```

And what I want is:

```
Hello, how are you?
With you?
```

How can I remove the empty lines?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @vagner-willian! I modified your question as it could have been clearer, which is why you started receiving -1's and close votes. If you could confirm that what I've written is actually what you're asking for and that I didn't misinterpret that would be great =)

Comment: Im brazilian, i translate using Google Translate. Sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is modify the text that you're passing into the textfield before you pass it in.

Dart has a [replaceAll](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html) method that should do the trick and takes in regex:

That would look something like:

```
myinputstring.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r))+'), '\n');
```

although you may have to modify the regex. What the regex is doing is looking for any sequence of two or more newlines (handling both \r, \n, and \r\n) and then replacing it with a single newline (again, you may want to change this to \r\n or \r).

Another way you could do it is with split and join.

```
myinputstring
    .split(new RegExp(r'(?:\r?\n|\r)'))
    .where((s) => s.trim().length != 0)
    .join('\n');
```

This time we're just splitting on any new line, then checking to see if the trimmed (to get rid of whitespace) parts in between are empty, and if they are ignoring them, and then joining the string back up.

Note that for performance reasons it might be a good idea to construct the regex object, save it somewhere else (i.e. a const), and then just use it in the replaceAll. I'm not 100% sure on the performance characteristics of regex in dart though so it may be fine; just my background in Java says that's always the recommended approach.

Comment: worked perfectly!!!
I apologize if I was not very clear on the question, because I am Brazilian, I understand little English.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Don't worry, everyone has different levels of skill in English, but some questions do get closed when they shouldn't when they're not completely clear to understand. Glad I could help =)