# Flutter: How to remove excessive new line in flutter

Tags: flutter

So I'm trying to create a flutter app, and I wanted my user to be able to enter some detail about their work and later on that detail will be shown. But I wanted to limit my user power to abuse the new line button on the keyboard.

So if user type like shown below on the text field:

```
Hello world
///this-is-new-line
///this-is-new-line
///this-is-new-line
///this-is-new-line
Hello again
```

The output will be:

```
Hello World
///Only-one-new-line
Hello again
```

How can I achieve this ? Thanks before

Comment: Refer to this link you can find out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778316/how-to-remove-only-lines-that-do-not-have-text-in-textfield

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove only lines that do not have text in TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778316/how-to-remove-only-lines-that-do-not-have-text-in-textfield)

Comment: I want to keep 1 new line but remove the other, meanwhile that post remove all of the line

Answer (score 0):

Using the links referenced in the comments, adjust it to only replace when there are three or more consective newlines, and replace with 2 newlines instead of 1.

```
myInput.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(?:[\t ]*(?:\r?\n|\r)){3,}'), '\n\n');
```

With a working DartPad example:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=2d97dc185b1299d6e951f6384df382bb